# Programmatically Merge PNG image into a PDF at an X/Y coordinate

Tags: python, pdf

I have an image that is posted to a Python App with PDF file.  I would like to merge those two files together at a specific X / Y coordinate on a specific page of the multi-page pdf.  I've looked at many frameworks like https://pypi.org/ and https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/ for PDFs and some have the ability to merge two PDFs but not to merge a PNG into that PDF.  Is anyone aware fo a possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a second PDF out of the PNG with some library ([FPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html) comes to mind), then merge. Like so:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image('imafe.png', 10.0, 10.0, link='', type='', w=10.0, h=10.0)
pdf.output('./output.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can do what you want. See the [insertImage](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/#Page.insertImage) method.